# Charge of a moving particle

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, charge

Is there an experiment that measures the electric charge of a moving particle, therefore proving "experimentally" that it is indeed the same as a static particle?

Comment: Well, you know Law of Conservation of Charge is a thing, so there's that...

Comment: Mass spectrometry demonstrates that charge does not change with velocity.

Comment: "*same as a static particle*"- Can we prove experimentally the charge of a static particle? Do you think HUP allow us to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Electric charge is lorentz invariant](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93879/)

Comment: I do expect charge to be be conserved by assumption, and also invariant under the transformations and according to the formulation of Maxwell's equations and all, but it seems to me that these are assumptions that need to be supported by experimental facts, before considering them as a 100% true statement. Otherwise the equations could be formulated to support other assumptions.

Comment: @lemon If I'm right, mass spectrometry only gives the mass-to-charge ratio of the particles, not their charge independently.

Comment: @Feynman I don't really know what you mean by HUP not allowing it. To my knowledge, Heisenberg's uncertainty principle is an inequality between parameters that are connected through Fourier transformation. I believe the electric charge is the constant of motion obtained from the U(1) symmetry of electromagnetism theory. Could you explain?

Comment: @Fatemeh That is correct but it is easy to demonstrate that mass is invariant (putting aside relativistic effects).

Comment: @lemon Yeah I suppose you're right, but isn't the magnetic field relatively small in the non-relativistic limit also?

Comment: some times ago I try to get an answer how differgent is a cloud of electrons in particle accelerators dependent of their velocity. This I asked because somewhere I read about shielded charge of electrons in relativistic cases.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose charge is not conserved when we have a change in velocity (i.e. when we move from static to moving or vice versa).  Then we wouldn't expect the change in the  Coulombs attraction to be solely dependent on $r$ 
$$F = k_e \frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$$ because as one particle attracts another, the values in the charges $q_1,q_2$ would change and so $F$ would change due to them as well. Note, I suspect if this were the case the principle of superposition would not hold because as you added more charges, they would all be affecting each other and make for a much much messier calculation than what is observed.

Therefore, verifying changes to the Coulomb attraction doesn't depend on charge should be sufficient to demonstrate charge is conserved. And Wikipedia provides such an experiment [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law)

Comment: also Bqv=mv^2/r would not work , and no circles would appear, contrary to this http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-fine-beam-of-electrons-moving-in-a-circular-path-while-in-a-uniform-146608.html

Comment: In the static case you're right. But when you're talking about moving charges, you would start seeing the magnetic force in addition to the Coulomb attraction. Therefore you should start using the Lorentz force, $F=q(E+v\times B)$. And as far as I know, the definition of the magnetic field $B$ depends on the assumption that the electric charge is observer independent.

Comment: Sending single, energetic ions through a static magnetic field repeatedly demonstrates that $qv \times B$ works, and that $q$ is not varying with particle velocity as we crank up the accelerating potential of the machine. Ion accelerators do this every day.